# how to find distance between consecutive points

Tags: matlab, distance, points

I have a matrix

```
A=[51.7365160000000 10.7978860000000;
   51.7366230000000 10.8319610000000;
   51.7389880000000 10.7849260000000;
   51.7424430000000 10.9195510000000;
   51.7443820000000 10.9157750000000;
   51.7448080000000 10.9160750000000;
   51.7523270000000 10.8756060000000;
   51.7525920000000 10.8758210000000;
   51.7526190000000 10.8738470000000;
   51.7526460000000 10.8763360000000;
   51.7528580000000 10.8477970000000;
   51.7530180000000 10.8776230000000];
```

The first column of A indicates latitude, the second column indicates longitude, with each row being a different point. I want to find the distance between consecutive points. I have used the function `pdist` in this way

```
a = pdist(A,'euclidean')';
```

but it gives the distance between all points and not only between consecutive points.

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the help of `pdist` you can use `squareform` to organize the data.

```
b = squareform(a);
```

The distances between neighbouring points are then the subdiagonals of this matrix.

```
dist = diag(b,1)
```

You can also easily calculate the distances manually

```
dist = sqrt(diff(A(:,1)).^2+diff(A(:,2)).^2)
```

Comment: +1: You can apply `diff` on both columns and have a shorter expression: `dist = sqrt(sum(diff(A).^2,2))`